# jQuery modal dialog is hidden by overlay div if dialog's parent has fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, overlay, positioning

One of my jQuery dialogs is defined within a div that has a fixed position (footer of page). When a modal jQuery dialog is opened jQuery creates an overlay div that hides the whole page and then puts the dialog to be opened on top having a higher z-index than the overlay div. Unfortunately any dialog that is rendered within a div with fixed position is overlayed by the overlay div although the modal dialog to be opened got a greater z-index then the overlay itself.

The following HTML code that I reduced for demonstration purposes to the problem shows the difference between a dialog within a non fixed position div and within a fixed position div:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/demo-webapp/faces/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/theme.css?ln=primefaces&amp;amp;v=2.2.1" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/demo-webapp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.1" />
    <title>CSS TEST</title><script type="text/javascript" src="/demo-webapp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.1"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/demo-webapp/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.1"></script>

    <script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("#dialog1").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true
            });

            jQuery("#dialog2").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true
            });
        });
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="z-index: 1; position: static;" onclick="jQuery('#dialog1').dialog('open')">
        position: static; /* default */
        <div id="dialog1" title="Dialog1"></div>
    </div>

    <div style="z-index: 1; position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 100px" onclick="jQuery('#dialog2').dialog('open')">
        position: fixed;
        <div id="dialog2" title="Dialog2"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

After loading the page it appears like that:

[image: Page after it is loaded]

**Dialog within a normal div is shown correctly**

The first dialog is defined with a non fixed positioned div and the dialog appears normally:

[image: First dialog appears correctly]

**Dialog within a fixed positioned div is overlayed**

Note, that when the second dialog defined within a fixed positioned div is shown, it cannot be clicked by the user since it is overlayed by the overlay div:

[image: Second dialog does not appear correctly]

Please not that z-index of the overlay div is in both cases 1001 and the z-index of the dialog is 1002. So the overlay div should not overlay the dialog, but unfortunately it's the case for dialogs within a fixed position div.

Since I am using Primefaces I am bound to jQuery 1.4.4. The problem occures in Firefox 4, latest Release and Safari, latest Release.

Can you reconstruct this issue and do you have a solution for that? Please note that I don't want to to place the dialog outside of the fixed positioned div *although it would solve the issue*. The reason for that is that I am using the templating mechanism of JSF and therefore the footer of my page will be filled dynamically with content -- in this case a popup dialog. It would break modularity if I have to place the dialog somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same thing here and I simply set the position to fixed on the overlay and it worked.

```
.ui-widget-overlay{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you for that easy solution although I cannot test anymore.

Comment: God bless you. That fixed my problem of overlay covering the modal on Android.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this solution that when included **at the bottom** of the page, template, etc. moves every dialog into the body tag.

```
<script>
    /* Bug fix that moves every dialog directly into the body tag since some jQueryUI dialogs are
       sometimes not placed above the overlay div due to their parent divs */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var body = $("html body")[0];
        $("div.ui-dialog").each(function() {
            $(this).appendTo(body);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Including this snippet into the header doesn't find `div.ui-dialog` tags since these divs gt their `ui-dialog` class dynamically injected. So this bug-fix has to be executed after.